# Modelagem Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

bom dia!

Estou com o seguinte problema nos relacionamentos usuário,formulário e grupo.
Da forma que foi modelado o relacionamento (CONTEM) se tornara uma tabela onde possuirá as chaves de usuário,formulário e grupo.MAS SE EU NÃO TIVER O FORMULÁRIO CADASTRADO NO SISTEMA(TENDO A PENAS AS CHAVES DE USUÁRIO E GRUPO),O QUE FAÇO NA TABELA (CONTEM) COM RELAÇÃO A FK QUE VIRIA DE FORMULÁRIO? POIS A CHAVE DE  FORMULÁRIO VAI COMO CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA PARA A TABELA (CONTEM) POIS O RELACIONAMENTO É DE N N N.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mas você não pode definir o Id do Formulário como default null?
Depois que o formulário for criado, você faz o vinculo.

Acho que se realmente é uma FK, deve ser definido no esquema do banco por questão de performance e garantir o modelo relacional do banco. Mas não vejo motivo para não definir como null.

Comment: é pq essa relação contem vai virar uma tabela e a chave de formulário nao pode ser nula nesta tabela !!Da erro! pois alem de FK ela é primaria

Comment: Entendi. No caso você está definindo uma obrigatoriedade. Neste caso você vai precisar criar o formulário. Pela modelagem você vai precisar criar o formulário obrigatoriamente antes de preencher a "CONTEM". Se no seu aplicativo o formulário for criado em momento diferente das demais entidades, sugiro que reformule o seu modelo. O modelo, por mais bonito que seja, precisa atender ao negocio e não o negocio atender ao modelo de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Crie apenas a  tabela de relacioanento **e não defina** os campos como **foreign key**, você poderá armazenas os valores normamente mesmo  se  tiver apenas  um valor.